# Why can't webdriver open (using Mac, python, Selenium)?

Tags: python, selenium

Python can't open the webdriver on Mac. The code is:

```
if platform == "win32":
    executable_path = os.path.join(dirname, 'geckodriver.exe') #must save the gecko file to same directory where python is. path to geckodriver (firefox drive/motor) on your machine
    print("Gecko (Firefox) filepath is: ", executable_path)
if platform == "darwin":
    executable_path = os.path.join(dirname, 'geckodriver') #must save the gecko file to same directory where python is. path to geckodriver (firefox drive/motor) on your machine
    print("Gecko (Firefox) filepath is: ", executable_path)

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options, executable_path=executable_path)
```

The error from Terminal is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/test.py", line 125, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options, executable_path=executable_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

The Geckodriver log is:

```
1631191187691   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:61381
1631191187701   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "--marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile4nfRRP"
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($HOME is /Users/username which is owned by user.)
```

I start the python file with this in Terminal:

```
sudo python3 /Users/username/Library/'Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs'/test.py
```

Downloaded the latest Firefox, and firefox webdriver on https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.29.1/geckodriver-v0.29.1-macos-aarch64.tar.gz

I have tried the other Mac firefox driver.

Any ideas why I get the error message and what to do?

Comment: Why do you run this as ``sudo``?

Comment: When I run without sudo I get this in Terminal: "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'"

Comment: Remove the log (backup it if needed) then run again without ``sudo``.

Comment: That worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked: Remove the log (backup it if needed) then run again without sudo.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.